# Find subarray in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and would like to find an array by specific payment_status:
My array below and I would like to return an array by payment_status.

```
[orders] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_price] => 995.94
                    [avg] => 995.940000
                    [count] => 1
                    [payment_status] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [total_price] => 779.64
                    [avg] => 779.640000
                    [count] => 1
                    [payment_status] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [total_price] => 1763.49
                    [avg] => 1763.490000
                    [count] => 1
                    [payment_status] => 3
                )

function get_sub_array((int)$payment_status) {

}
```

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Thats great, so what have you tried?

Comment: Function Interface is ready but the contents are not there? Try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array('orders' => array
        (
            0 => Array
                (
                    'total_price' => 995.94,
                    'avg' => 995.940000,
                    'count' => 1,
                    'payment_status' => 1
                ),

            1 => Array
                (
                    'total_price' => 779.64,
                    'avg' => 779.640000,
                    'count' => 1,
                    'payment_status' => 2
                ),

            2 => Array
                (
                    'total_price' => 1763.49,
                    'avg' => 1763.490000,
                    'count' => 1,
                    'payment_status' => 3
                )
        ));

function get_sub_array($payment_status,$arr) {
  $arrRet = array();
  foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    if($val['payment_status'] == $payment_status)
      array_push($arrRet,$val);
  }
 return $arrRet;
}

$arrRes = get_sub_array(1,$arr['orders']);
print_r($arrRes);
```

Comment: Thanks. Right code below:  public static function get_order_by_payment_status($arr, $payment_status) {
    
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arr as $order) {
     if ($order['payment_status'] == $payment_status) {
      $result = $order;
     }
    }

    return $result;
   }

Answer (score 1):

This would work I think.

```
function get_sub_array($arr, $payment_status) {
    foreach($arr as $item) {
        if($item['payment_status'] === $payment_status) {
            return $item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if more than 1 item.?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to retrieve multiple orders with the same status, to return them all you could do:

```
    function get_sub_array($orders, $payment_status) {

        $result = array();
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            if ($order['payment_status'] == $payment_status) {
                array_push($result, $order);
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter`. For example if you want a sub array containing all values with payment status `3`:

```
$sub_array = array_filter($arr['orders'],function($val){ 
    return $val['payment_status'] === 3; 
});
```